# Symfony2 service unable to find template

Tags: php, email, symfony, templates, twig

I've just pulled an all-nighter trying to get this to work, and I'm probably missing something foolish, but help me out.

I have a symfony2 service which sends emails.  I have injected the `@templating` service into my service's constructor like so:

#### services.yml

```
order_service:
    class: AppBundle\Services\OrderService
    arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@mailer", "@templating" ]
```

#### OrderService.php

```
/**
 * @var EntityManager
 */
protected $em;

protected $twig;

protected $mailer;    

public function __construct(EntityManager $_entityManager, $_mailer, $_twig)
{
    $this->em = $_entityManager;
    $this->mailer = $_mailer;
    $this->twig = $_twig;
}
```

I have my templates located in `AppBundle/Resources/views/Emails`.  Further down in my service is the function that tries to send emails.

```
protected function send_emails($vendors, $order)
{
    $customer = $order->getCustInfo();

    // Send email(s) to customer
    foreach ($order->getVouchers() as $voucher)
    {
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Voucher # ' . $voucher->getId())
            ->setFrom('from_address@foobar.com')
            ->setTo($customer->email)
            ->setBody($this->twig->render(
                'Emails/email-voucher.html.twig', [
                    'order'     =>  $order,
                    'voucher'   =>  $voucher,
                    'customer'  =>  $customer
                ]
            ), 'text/html');

        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }
}
```

I always get the error `Unable to find template \"Emails/email-voucher.html.twig\".`

So, here's a summary of what I've tried:

- Basically everything suggested on similar StackOverflow questions
- Moving templates to `app/Resources/views`
- Every path/relative path I can think of in the call to `->render()`
- Pulling my hair out

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if your service lies in the same namespace as it's your template, that does not mean that you can call it directly like that. Did you tried the way you render normal controller templates, like this:

```
->setBody($this->twig->render(
            'AppBundle:Emails:email-voucher.html.twig', [
                'order'     =>  $order,
                'voucher'   =>  $voucher,
                'customer'  =>  $customer
            ]
        ), 'text/html');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is why I love SO.  No, I hadn't tried that particular path -- and I don't really understand why it works, but it does.  Why am I able to skip part of the path?  The full path to the template is `AppBundle/Resources/views/Emails/email-voucher.html.twig`, so it seems so counterintuitive to leave out the `Resources/views` part...

Comment: Symfony uses those shortcuts and automatically resolves them to full path of your template. In short, given the following `AppBundle:Emails:email-voucher.html.twig` the framework would take `AppBundle` of it and convert it to its original bundle path `AppBundle/Resources/views`. Then comes `Emails:` which represents the directory you placed your template, so we get `AppBundle/Resources/views/Emails` and the rest is your template filename.